# Why does cv.glmnet not use the same lambda sequence across different folds to find the hypertuning parameter lambda?

Tags: cross-validation, regularization, glmnet

I assumed that cv.glmnet works as follows:

1. Generate multiple glmnet fits for the entire data, presumably for automated lambda sequence using coordinate descent
2. Use the lambdas gotten in step 1, and find rmse for different cross validation folds, again using glmnet
3. The lambda with the best RMSE across folds is chosen as lambda_min
4. Return the overall model (in step1) corresponding to lambda_min

But the github code (https://github.com/cran/glmnet/blob/master/R/cv.glmnet.R) suggests that the different cv folds use their own lambda sequence.  Why was this change done in cv.glmnet code ? How does it add up ?

I looked at the web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html and it seems that we can compute a elastic model for any specified lambda within the range of lambda sequence used, once the model has been computed. So, while we use appropriate warm starts for each cross validation fold, but the original lambda sequence only acts as the lambda grid from which we choose the perfect lambda. Is my interpretation correct ?

Comment: The heuristics used to construct the `lambda` sequence are based on the training data. In CV, you're explicitly using different training data for each fold, so the heuristics will produce different results.

Comment: But do we not need to find the cross validation error for the lambda sequence found in step 1 ? And cv error is nothing but a lasso model with that lambda ? Let say y1, y2, y3 be the lambdas obtained in step1. Now we to pick one of them by cross validation. So for each lambda in (y1, y2, y3), we build glmnet model for each cross validation fold, and find average rmse. The lambda that gives the minimum rmse should be chosen. say y2. The model corresponding to y1 (in step 1) should be returned

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Why would `y1` be the correct answer if `y2` has the lowest error?

Comment: Sorry for the typo.. i meant y2 only..But then why is a new lambda sequence being used in every fold, as we need to compute cv errors for a set of lambda only

Comment: I looked at the https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html and it seems that we can compute a elastic model for any specified lambda within the range of lambda sequence used, once the model has been computed. So, while we use appropriate warm starts for each cross validation fold, but the original lambda sequence only acts as the lambda grid from which we choose the perfect lambda. Is it correct ?

Comment: Hastie is one of the main authors of all things `glmnet` so it's probably safe to take his word for it.

Comment: Yeah, that's true...but do you also think my interpretation of his description and code is correct ? Thanks Sycorax for your help

Comment: Perhaps you could revise your question in light of your findings at that stanford.edu page and ask a question that better matches your current level of understanding and research.